# Flat File data getting imported only after converting into UTF-8

Tags: sql-server, encoding, utf-8, ssis, ssis-2012

I have the data in the following format in a flat file -

```
100|200|Mar  4 2016  9:48AM|abc|sample data
100|201|Mar  4 2016  9:49AM|abc|sample data
```

Using the Flat File Source, I am trying to insert it into the destination SQL table. The current flat file does not have any encoding associated with it.

Here is the preview from the Flat File Source after detecting the delimiter -

[image: Flat File Source Preview]

Here is the data after insertion -

[image: Blank Data in Destination]

I changed the encoding of the flat file to UTF-8 using Notepad++ (Encoding -> Encode in UTF-8). I then run the package all the data has got inserted including the blank line (I am not sure why it detected the blank line).

There are about 10k files I would need to load. Can someone tell me what the problem is? Why is it SSIS not detecting the data even though it shows correctly in the preview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem. All I had to do was when building up the Flat File Source, I kept the 'Unicode' checkbox ticked and then it detected the data correctly as well as identifying the exact rows i.e. 2 in this case. Post these changes, the data is getting inserted successfully.

It is strange however why SSIS doesn't work when it does show valid data in preview.